# Change query result format sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to do the following :

```
def EMA(file):

current_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
five_minutes_ago = current_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
sub_within_las_five_min = db.session.query(visits).filter((visits.date > five_minutes_ago),(visits.name == file)).all()
a = len(sub_within_las_five_min)
return a
```

I get this error :

> InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 1 -
>   probably unsupported type. [SQL: u'SELECT visits.id AS visits_id,
>   visits.name AS visits_name, visits.date AS visits_date \nFROM visits
>   \nWHERE visits.date > ? AND visits.name = ?'] [parameters:
>   ('2016-02-20 12:06:43.974000', (u'vagrant.txt',))]

I know the problem is caused by the (u'vagrant.txt',) because i tried to put 'vagrant.txt' instead of file and it works . the file name is generated from this view :

```
@app.route('/api/test/', methods=['GET'])
def catalogue1():
catalogue = db.session.query(Content.name).all()
for i in range(len(catalogue)):
j= catalogue[i]
s = EMA(j)
return str(s)
```

Can someone help me , i want to change the format of the db.session.query(content.name) to fit my first query .

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `file` attribute that you pass to `EMA` is a tuple rather than a string, so this might help:

```
def EMA(file):
    filename = file[0]
    current_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    five_minutes_ago = current_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
    sub_within_las_five_min = db.session.query(visits).filter((visits.date > five_minutes_ago),(visits.name == filename)).all()
    a = len(sub_within_las_five_min)
    return a
```